# nginx - serve content from inside a zip (jar) archive

Tags: nginx, jar, zip, archive, static-content

Is there any nginx module for serving static content from within an archive, Zip / Jar at least, without extracting it?

Pretty sure this wouldn't work for all archives, such as .tar, because of the lack of seeking, but it should be possible to implement with a .zip efficiently.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in very short. For ordinary zip compressed file, plain text output is possible, there is [nginx unzip module](https://github.com/youzee/nginx-unzip-module).